# Mark import as used for IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have an import statement of an implicit function that IntelliJ thinks is unused due to a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6003). Whenever I execute the `Organize Imports` command, IntelliJ removes that import line. Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to leave this line alone?

Comment: I really don't think so. Have you tried to go to a previous / newer version of intellij?

Comment: I am on the latest IDEA (12.1.4) and Scala plugin (0.19.299). Moving backwards in each dimension will introduce worse bugs :)

Comment: Introduce a dummy, never-used, well-commented private method using the imported class?

Comment: @JBNizet, that would replace the unused import issue with an unused method warning...

Comment: My current solution is to add this implicit to a trait and mix in that trait.

Comment: Intellij usually thinks the import is unused, when the JAR cannot be found.. i've noticed this before so you may have a problem in the dependencies.

Comment: @LaloInDublin I have the problem when the class/trait/object is in the same source folder :)

Comment: Try to disable imports inspection for that particular import.

Comment: You can add at least one explicit call to this function. IDEA underlines implicit usages with gray line by default. To find specific implicit function which was used put cursor over implicit and use Navigate / Implicit conversion action to find its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is fixed in 1.2.66 - see the bug report.